# Paypal returns an empty $_POST with mozilla

Tags: php, paypal

Here is my HTML code.  My code runs properly on chrome and opera but it is not working on firefox.

```
<form name="confirmation" id="confirmation" method="post" 
    action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">

     <input type='hidden' name='business' value='xyz@gmail.com'>
     <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_cart'>
     <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
     <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
     <input type="hidden" name="country" value="Singapore">
     <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
     <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"> 
     <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' 
         value='http://website.com/demo/myProject/'>
     <input type='hidden' name='return'
         value='http://website.com/demo/myProject/cart/payment-confirm.html'>

     <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" 
         value="http://website.com/demo/myProject/cart/payment-confirm.html" />

     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $countRows;?>" id="cartCount" />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried building it with an NVP based API?
I have built my own script using cUrl requests and the Paypal NVP commands. Works like a charm on all browsers.

Comment: What do you mean: "Not working"?

Comment: Not working means when it is return to notify_url after successful payment ...i received $_POST empty on return page in mozilla while in chrome i get a $_POST with all information  regarding product details and buyer details

Answer (score 1):

The data is going to the IPN url. Log the $_POST data to a file from the script at the IPN URL and see what you are getting. I think if you turn off the IPN, you may then get the data on the notify_url (been a while though, not 100% sure on that part).

Comment: But if the IPN is turn off then it has to not display data on chrome ecen but the problem occurs only in mozilla

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but $_POST is only empty if i return in less than 2 seconds to the sellers website like e.g. using PayPasl "Auto Return". If i return manually and click to slow on the retrun to sellers website button it all works fine.
Firefox seems to be more secure than other browsers and does not let you send $_POST from a secured domain (https://) to non-secured one (http://). The offical PayPal and secure way is to use the "Payment Data Transfer (PDT)"  method which uses GET over https instead of POST over http.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/